# BigQuery function similar to STRING(json_expr) that handles null values?

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I'm looking for a BigQuery function that lets me parse a JSON value that can be nullable. I want the function to return an error when the JSON value is not a string (e.g. number or boolean), but it should return NULL when the value is 'null'.

If XXX is the function, I would like:

```
SELECT XXX(JSON '"purple"') to return the SQL STRING "purple".
SELECT XXX(JSON 'null') to return a SQL NULL.
SELECT XXX(JSON 'true') to return an error.
SELECT XXX(JSON '15') to return an error.
```

The standard **STRING(json_expr)** converter does not work, because it fails for 'null'.

**SAFE.STRING(json_expr)** works for '"purple"' and 'NULL', but it returns NULL instead of throwing an error for 'true' and '15'.

**LAX_STRING(json_expr)** works for '"purple"' and 'NULL', but it returns "true" and "15" for 'true' and '15', instead of throwing an error.

Is there a function that acts like **STRING(json_expr)** but handles 'null' fields?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try IFNULL() function in your query:

```
IFNULL(expr, null_result)
```

If you have a sample query might be able to replicate.

Reference:https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conditional_expressions#ifnull